# How to get number of tokens in the sentence in keras

Tags: python, nlp, token, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I have a sentence and a pre-trained tokenizer. I want to calculate the number of tokens in the sentence, **without special tokens**. I use the [code](https://huggingface.co/bert-base-cased) from HuggingFace.

```py
from transformers import BertTokenizer, TFBertModel
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
text = "I want to know the number of tokens in this sentence!!!"
encoded_input = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='tf')
output = model(encoded_input)
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use `encode` method with setting `add_special_tokens` to `False` or basically use `tokenize` method.

```
encoded_input = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='tf', add_special_tokens=False)
encoded_input.input_ids.shape[1]
```

and

```
tokenized_input = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
len(tokenized_input)
```